# Load method from shared library which calls method that is implemented in children class

Tags: c++, linker, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I know that is title a little confusing but let me explain:

I have class A like this:

```
class A : public Parent
{
public:
    //other methods and stuff
    void run() 
    {
         execute(arr, size_of_array);
    }

    virtual void execute(int tab[], int size) = 0;
};
```

And I have class B which implements this method execute like this:

```
class B : public A
{
public:
    void execute(int tab[], int size)
    {
        //do something here
    }
};
```

Class B is in static library, class A is in dynamic library.
In main program I want to load symbol "run" and call this method, so that this method will call execute function from that static library. Is this possible?
I suppose that I need somehow to link this static library to shared library so there won't be any undefined references?

I'm a little stuck here so I would appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: `run` is a non-static member function and will require an instance of `A` to invoke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer:  It works the way you want it to.

The long answer: Class B is defined in the static library.  If you have an instance of class B then it was created in the static library or something linked to the static library.

Because this class has a virtual method, each instance includes a pointer to a vtable (a hidden table of pointers to the actual implementations of the virtual methods.)   This vtable is generated in the static library and the pointer in the actual B object points to it.  Thus when the method in class A calls execute, it finds the vtable via the pointer in the object itself and calls the method via an offset into the vtable.   Thus it is using the vtable in the static lilbrary and ends up in the execute method as defined in the static library.

Comment: "If you have an instance of class B then it was created in the static library or something linked to the static library." Here you mean if I have instance of class B in my main program? First of all, this static library is NOT linked with main program. This is completely seperated program/project. So, in my main program I have only definitions of methods. I know that I can't have instance of class A because of that virtual execute method. Let's try another way. Would it be simpler if I have shared library instead of static?

Comment: I believe that then I could load lib file into main, create instance of class B and I could call method execute on class B, since class B inherits class A?

Comment: This is not Java (or any of the other interpreted languages) There is no such thing as a class loader. When  you create a B, you *MUST* have the declaration of B available, which means if B is declared in the static library you can only create it in the static library or in code that is already linked to the static library.

Comment: It is extremely rare for you to have to load a dynamic library "by hand".  That happens automatically for you because your code is linked against the library.

Comment: So, it is not posible for me to link static library (in which is class B) to link with my main program. Let me explaine what am I doing. I'm doing program for testing algorithms. I have program my_program which is main program. User can install this program and then he can creates projects. Lets sa that he creates project Sorting with algorithm BubbleSort. This execute method is actually a implementation ob BubbleSort. What is then, by your opinion the best approach for this? Can I create shared lib with class B and then create instance of class B and call run?

Comment: OK you've found one of the rare cases in which you do need to load a dynamic library by hand.  However the algorithm to be tested must be in the dynamic library (so it can be loaded at run time rather than hardwired into the program at link time.)  This is moving beyond the scope of your original question so I suggest that 1) you research dynamically loading libraries and calling methods on those libraries. 2) write some code based on your research, then 3) if it doesn't work come back and ask a different question here.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your pointers. Since your answer answers my question, I will accept it. Thank you.